# Firebase notification sent to an audience does not reach all devices it should

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an interesting situation. For some time I have been collecting an audience based on a single user property. Now it has significant amount of devices included. The audience is for ios devices.

I then sent a notification to that audience and I that see some of the devices receive that notification, some don't. Why could that be?

Experiments show that devices that don't receive the notification, receive a notification targeted to single device only. Also they receive notifications send to all users. That makes me suspect that this is related to audiences. I have verified that at least one device that does not receive the notifications has proper value for the user property in question. However, it is possible that the during the past days device has had varying values for the property, based on the account used for logging in to the app. Sometimes it has had two versions of the same app installed at the same time.

I have similar audience for Android and as far as I can tell, all members in the audience receive the notification.

The audience's are in thousands, so the information is based only on few devices I see around me, plus Firebase and Google Analytics.

From Firebase documentation I learn that "*a user is a permanent member of an audience after they are assigned to it*", which explains why two opposite audiences combined may be bigger than the total number of users, but it makes it even more difficult to understand why someone having the properties required for the audience would not belong to it.

Any ideas on how to debug this or what could be the reason. Or even better, how to fix this? Since this is production software, I can not send excessive number of notifications to try different things.

Answer (score 4):

While I probably still don't know all of the possible reasons for this, there are at least two things that seemed to have some effect on this in our case and third one that could have been the reason if not correctly understood:

1) Our app did register list of values with single call to setUserPropertyString and in some cases the string did exceed the 24 character limit, which caused the property not to be set and the user/device not to be included in an audience.

2) When sending the notification to iOS app, the "High" prority should be selected, otherwise it is possible, or even likely that the notification does not reach the device.

3) Firebase console texts for combining multiple audiences are not all that clear, especially the "does not ..." texts could be clearer in my opinion. This is what they mean in practice:

- includes all of == AND, notification is sent if user is included in all selected audiences
- includes at least one of == OR, notification is sent if user is included in at least one of the selected audiences
- does not include all of == NAND, notification is sent if user is *not* included in all of the selected audiences, but user can be included in some of them
- does not include at least one of == NOR, notification is sent only if user is *not* included in any of the selected audiences